# How does `d3.forceSimulation` adds `{x:number,y:number...}` on the data items?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My code looks something like this:

```
update = (props) => {
  if (!this.rootEl) {
    return;
  }
  const { viewportWidth, viewportHeight, cards } = props;
  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(cards)
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(viewportWidth / 2, viewportHeight / 2))
    .on('tick', this.tick);
};

tick = () => {
  const { viewportWidth, viewportHeight, cards } = this.props;
  const svg = d3.select(this.rootEl).attr('width', viewportWidth).attr('height', viewportHeight);

  const circle = svg.selectAll('circle').data(cards);
  const createCircle = chain => chain
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', d => 22);
  createCircle(circle.enter().append('circle'));
  createCircle(circle.transition(t));
  circle.exit().remove();
}
```

I don't understand what kind of "magic" d3 is doing to add the `x`, `y`, `vx`, `vy` to the data inside the `tick`?

For example if `d3` is used outside the `tick` function doesn't have those properties added to the data. `simulation` variable is never used and the `const svg = d3.select...` is never linked.

I can't think of anything except a messy global state. Is this some kind of global or how they are linked?

I'm new to d3 and I think there is too much magic :)

Comment: There is no magic here, and it does not depend on `tick`. The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) clearly says: *"The following properties are assigned by the simulation:

index - the node’s zero-based index into nodes
x - the node’s current x-position
y - the node’s current y-position
vx - the node’s current x-velocity
vy - the node’s current y-velocity"*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.

- When you call `d3.forceSimulation(cards)`;
- The `cards` array of objects that I pass into the simulation are changed;
- Then when I use the `cards` again those are changed;

As I'm using react, this is not the best, but there are workarounds.